# Android Add Items One By One Into a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to find out how to do that:
 - I have an activity with a ScrollView and inside it I have a LinearLayout (R.id.my_layout)
- I nedd to add TextView programmatically so I'm doing this:

I load the main XML layout via seContentView, I refer to my LinearLayout inside the ScrollView as "mLayout" and so on.
I load a list of names from a file and with a function called populateList()I do:

```
private void populateList() {
    try {

        for (final String team : mTeams) {
            rCount++;
            addRow(team);
        }
    }
```

The addRow() method just create a new LinearLayout (mRow),  a TextView, 2 Button, add the TextView and the 2 Buttons to the LinearLayout, and then I use addView to add the new mRow to the mLayout.
Everything is working fine, but the ScrollView is shown only when i finished creating the list (so when the populateList() ends). What I would like to do is to show the rows one by one in sequence to give the activty a better look and a bit of animation.
Is there a way to do this?
I hope i was able to explain it :-)
Thank you

Comment: Yes Sir, you see all i'd is create a new Thread, and do your creation and looping in that thread, and use handler or ui communication methods to connect to your ui thread and add it, with that you will have your items in a sequence..

Comment: How can I modify the UI from another thread?

Comment: i will drop a code for you

Comment: I wil really appreciate it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { // i am creating the new thread

        @Override
        public void run() {             
            // so call populateList() function here
        }
    }).start();
```

and for your `addRow(String string)` method the place you call `View.addView();` edit it this way  and place the following code in your `addRow(String string)` method

```
View.post(new new Runnable() {// view here is mlayout the scrollView.

        @Override
        public void run() {             
            mlayout.addView(yourview); // note yourview should be final,
        //eclipse might help you with that
        }
    });
```

remember to declare `mlayout` globally, so you do not have to attach `final`

Comment: I will try it and I'll let you know :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: PERFECT! It works!! I had to add a thread.sleep(100) on the populate ilist "for" to slow it down a bit :-) I Read a lot of posts reagrding this issue but no easy solution, but you gave me one in 5 minutes :-) Thank you! Unfotunately I cannot give vote due to low reputaion :-(

Comment: lol.. Yes Sir, it did, and yeah nyce, but it should be static like this `Thread.sleep(1000)` also its in millie seconds so if you want 1 second is 10*100 or 1000; 1 minute is 60*100 or 6000, depends on your choice;that's just btw, great to be of help,if you do not have any additional problems to this problem, you can accept it as an answer :) @Pecana

Comment: Sir, you will see some checkmark underneath the score to the left of my answer click it and you will see a green paint on the checkmark, means its been accepted.. [check here for more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) @Pecana

Comment: DOne, and forgive me for y stupid questions :-) Thanks again !